# Is that possible to create a comparison operator from string?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a function that will produce an if condition from a predefined array.

for example:

```golang
package errors

type errorCase struct {
    // This is the field I need to get in another struct
    Field        string
    // The comparison operator
    TestOperator string
    // The value that the expected one should not with equal...
    WrongValue   interface{}
}

var ErrorCases = []*errorCase{ {
    "MinValue",
    "<",
    0,
}, {
    "MaxValue",
    "==",
    0,
}}
```

Actually I made a new function with a for loop that iterate through all of these "error cases"

```golang
func isDirty(questionInterface models.QuestionInterface) bool {
    for _, errorCase := range errors.ErrorCases {
        s := reflect.ValueOf(&questionInterface).Elem()
        value := s.Elem().FieldByName(errorCase.Field)

        // At this point I need to create my if condition
        // to compare the value of the value var and the wrong one
        // With the given comparison operator
    }

    // Should return the comparison test value
    return true
}
```

Is that possible to create an if condition like that?
With the reflect package?

I think this is possible but I don't find where I should start.

Comment: I don’t think it is possible. You have to use a `switch` instruction where each case is for a possible operator.

Comment: @chmike Yes this is my second option I thought

Comment: A function is necessary for this.

Comment: @Flimzy A function of what? A custom one?

Comment: Yes, you need to write a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. I built a generic comparison library like this once before.

A comparison, in simple terms, contains 3 parts:

1. A **value** of some sort, on the left of the comparison.
2. An **operator** (`=`, `<`, `>`, ...).
3. A **value** of some sort, on the right of the comparison.

Those 3 parts, contain only two different types - **value** and **operator**. I attempted to abstract those two types into their base forms.

- **value** could be anything, so we use the empty interface - `interface{}`.
- **operator** is part of a finite set, each with their own rules.

```
type Operator int

const (
    Equals Operator = 1
)
```

Evaluating a comparison with an `=` sign has only one rule to be valid - both values should be of the same type. You can't compare `1` and `hello`. After that, you just have to make sure the values are the same.

We can implement a new meta-type that wraps the requirement for evaluating an `operator`.

```
// Function signature for a "rule" of an operator.
type validFn func(left, right interface{}) bool

// Function signature for evaluating an operator comparison.
type evalFn func(left, right interface{}) bool

type operatorMeta struct {
    valid []validFn
    eval  evalFn
}
```

Now that we've defined our types, we need to implement the rules and comparison functions for `Equals`.

```
func sameTypes(left, right interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.TypeOf(left).Kind() == reflect.TypeOf(right).Kind()
}

func equals(left, right interface{}) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(left, right)
}
```

Awesome! So we can now validate that our two **values** are of the same type, and we can compare them against each other if they are. The last piece of the puzzle, is mapping the **operator** to its appropriate rules and evaluation and having a function to execute all of this logic.

```
var args = map[Operator]operatorMeta{
    Equals: {
        valid: []validFn{sameTypes},
        eval:  equals,
    },
}

func compare(o Operator, left, right interface{}) (bool, error) {
    opArgs, ok := args[o]
    if !ok {
        // You haven't implemented logic for this operator.
    }

    for _, validFn := range opArgs.valid {
        if !validFn(left, right) {
            // One of the rules were not satisfied.
        }
    }

    return opArgs.eval(left, right), nil
}
```

Let's summarize what we have so far:

- Abstracted a basic comparison into a **value** and **operator**.
- Created a way to validate whether a pair of **values** are valid for an operator.
- Created a way to evaluate an **operator**, given two **values**.

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/mIXho3ykWOF)

I hope that I gave some insight into how you can approach this. It's a simple idea, but can take some boilerplate to get working properly.

Good luck!